# Terminal Bash Moving specific extensions to folder and keep duplicates

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal, mv

I am trying to organize all files by file extension into their respected folder. While keeping duplicates. Parent Folders and Subfolders are also present
I want to bulk move specific file extensions and keep duplicates when I move specific files to a location that have the same file name.

I tried manually by dragging but will not give the option to keep duplicates unless i do 1 at a time. Time Consuming

---

I have tried the following

```
find /Users/Pictures -type f -name "*.png" -exec mv -i * /Users/Desktop/PNG  < /dev/null \;
```

Tried the following as well but duplicates are not moved

```
find /Users/Pictures -type f -name "*.png"
mv -i * /Users/Desktop/PNG < /dev/null
```

---

Would love a code that will do the following

Example of Current Status

```
Folder(A) > 1.png

Folder(B) > Subfolder(b) > SubSubFolder(bb) > 1.png

Folder(C) > Subfolder(c) > 1.png
```

---

Desired Result

```
PNG Folder 
        1.png

        1 Copy.png

        1 Copy(2).png
```

Comment: Do you really have a user whose account name is `Desktop` though?

Comment: No I took out the name but should not matter. so it was User/Name/Desktop/png

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
find /User/Pictures -type f -iname '*.png' | xargs -I % mv  --backup=numbered  % /User/Desktop/PNG/
```

This will move the files to `/User/Desktop/PNG` and rename them as follows: `1.png` `1.png.~1~` `1.png.~2~` ...etc.

This requires you to install a version of `mv` which supports this option, such as GNU `coreutils`. The standard *BSD `mv` on Mac OS does not have this option.

Comment: The `--backup` feature is GNU only, though. The OP probably doesn't have GNU `mv`.

Comment: @tripleee: Is it possible for him to install GNU `mv` : `brew install mv --with-default-names`

Comment: Sure; but the answer should probably be explicit about any portability concerns, especially when the question specifically targets a platform where this answer will not work out of the box.

Comment: You need to have Homebrew installed separately before that can work anyway. Just leave it at "figure out a way to install GNU `mv`" IMHO.

Comment: mv: illegal option -- -
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
mv: illegal option -- -
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: @UntiedMyMind: please try to install the GNU `mv`: try : `brew install coreutils --with-default-names` if it installs correctly, restart your terminal window and the commands above.

Comment: I used the following link to install GNU https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/
However the command still does not work and I receive the error message I posted

Comment: @UntiedMyMind: try to close your terminal window and open it again.

Comment: @navaro still getting the following message 
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
mv: illegal option -- -
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: @Navaro when i use 
brew install mv --with-default-names

the last line says 
Error: invalid option: --with-default-names

Comment: @UntiedMyMind: Unfortunately, I've never used Mac OS. I have no Macbook to test it, hence I cannot help you with this unfortunately. You can ask another question on how to install GNU mv on Mac Os or take a look at this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities

Comment: @Navaro
I am getting the following message when i installed Coreutils 

Commands also provided by macOS have been installed with the prefix "g".
If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Comment: @UntiedMyMind: What is the message you get?

Comment: @UntiedMyMind: Try to add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` then close your terminal windows then open a new terminal window and exectute the following `which gmv` tell me the output of this command.

Comment: @Navaro I get the following message       /usr/local/bin/gmv

Comment: @UntiedMyMind: Now you can use `gmv` instead of `mv`. To be sure, run ` man gmv` to make sure it is the GNU version of `mv`.

Comment: Sorry guys this does not work and looks like my unix codes are all messed up now.
I am going to try a different site see if they can correct my Terminal
Thanks for the efforts at @tripleee